# ios remote notification not beeing marked as read

Tags: ios, ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Ok, so I've wrote a small app that receives remote notifications that I handle in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and I also check the userDict passed to `didFinishLaunch`.

However, the notifications is sill listed as "unread" in the notification-center on iOS 5 (there is a tiny blue dot to the left of them). How can I make it so that after a user has clicked a notification it either goes away, or it's marked as read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way in iOS 5.0 to only remove one entry. Quoting [iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 5.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html):

**Springboard**
Push and local notifications for apps appear in the new Notification Center in iOS 5. Notification Center displays notifications that are considered "unread.” To accommodate push and local notifications that have no unread status, set your application’s badge count to 0 to clear that app’s notifications from Notification Center.

Comment: Actually, what did the trick was setting it to something it wasn't before (can be 0) then setting it to what you wanted it to be (as this might be the same as what you set it to to remove the "notifications")

Comment: Thank you, @Alxandr! Setting it to something it wasn't before does the trick.